# Update query in after insert trigger

Tags: sql, .net, oracle, triggers, database-trigger

I want to update a table named 'B' based on insertion on table 'A',matching between two tables are 'A' table column named 'IDENT' and B table 
 `REGION_CODE_MW||MW_ID` (combination).I used following trigger but it throws error like(popup)'Enter Binds for New'.What is wrong in trigger

```
   create or replace 
trigger testrigger
after insert 
on A
for each row 
declare 
link_id varchar2(200);
BEGIN
  IF(:NEW.IDENT != '') THEN
    link_id := :NEW.IDENT;
  end if; 
  UPDATE B
  SET IMPL_DSGN    ='Yes',
    EQUIP_AVAILABLE='Yes'
  where REGION_CODE_MW
    ||MW_ID=link_id;
    END;
```

Comment: At least part of the problem is that the variables `COUNTER` and `MW_ID_LINK` are never declared.

Comment: I updated my question ,now no errors ,but issue now is whenever an insertion on A no updation happening on table B,any issue??

Comment: do you have a column named as `link_id` or similar, in table A?

Comment: in A i have column 'IDENT' and in B i am matching with combination of REGION_CODE_MW
    ||MW_ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `IF(:NEW.IDENT != '') THEN`, `IF(:NEW.IDENT is not null ) THEN` may be used

( comparison is wrong ).

Moreover, `update statement` should be in that `if statement` :

```
 IF( :NEW.IDENT is not null ) THEN
    link_id := :NEW.IDENT;

  UPDATE B
     SET IMPL_DSGN    ='Yes',
         EQUIP_AVAILABLE='Yes'
   WHERE REGION_CODE_MW||MW_ID=link_id;
 END IF;
```

Comment: thanks a lot,,strange is not null  is working rather than != ''

Comment: @peter, it isn't strange, since `''` is `NULL` in Oracle, an `=` or `!=` comparison will always return false. That is, both `NULL = NULL` and `NULL != NULL` will always be false. For example, try `SELECT * FROM dual WHERE '' != NULL` - nothing will be returned. Replace `!=` with `=` and *still* nothing will be returned. Hope this helps.